# Separating storage of site users from admin users in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I'm just getting started with a website based on Orchard and have a question related to user accounts and authentication.

There will be **site administrators/editors** of various kinds responsible for updating the site with content. For these types of users the built-in role and user management in Orchard is a perfect fit. Regular **site users**, however, must be stored in an **external legacy system**, should never have access to the site dashboard and should not be visible under the "Users" tab in the dashboard even to administrators (they are managed completely by the external system).

What would be the proper way to implement this in Orchard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own membership provider. You can take examples from the gallery that are doing authentication, such as oAuth or AD modules.

Comment: And then have some sort of switch within the provider that routes the handling of accounts to different stores based on role, you mean?

Comment: Also, if I implement an IMembershipService that returns IUsers that do not correspond to content items in Orchard (owned by external system), what should I set the IUser.ContentItem to? It can't be null or just a dummy (new:ed) ContentItem instance, since various extension methods used by themes seem to depend on being able to work with it. Any advice on this?

Comment: I found this discussion related to externalizing user storage: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/400650 - the general advice from developer "pszmyd" seems to boil down to either keeping copies of the external users in the Orchard database, or replace the Orchard.Users module completely. Is that really the way to go? In that case it's way more complicated than I would have imagined when I first looked at the IMembershipService interface.

Comment: It might be, depending on how deep your requirements need to go. But content items can be created on the fly.

Comment: Marking this as accepted; a bit disappointed at the abstraction of the membership and user concepts in the current version of Orchard though - would have been nice to be able to swap out the default implementations without needing to keep "shadow copies" of external users in the Orchard database.

Comment: Please file a bug and consider a contribution to fix it.